# How to finish current animation in Unity3D Animator?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animation created in Animator where a part of UI transitions from one side of the screen to another.
How to add an option to immediately finish the animation and put animated object in its final place?

Because animations are created by 3rd party and I don't know the locations upfront, I can't just stop the animation and set position of the object to the final one.

Thanks

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-do-you-allow-animations-to-interrupt-each-other.313216/

Comment: Almost. Thread is about changing animation states immediately. I don't want to change the state, I want the current one to finish immediately.

Comment: Apology for misunderstanding.. Are you saying that you don't know final position of object in an animation? Well If you can see animation component, how hard is it to open animation window and find that out?

Comment: Quite difficult when it's done at runtime and you don't know how someone else is going to modify the animation. How many objects there will be, from where to where they are going to flow etc. In other words, I have to set the animation on last frame.

Comment: Well. If that is the case, I must answer your question now: Use `AnimationState.length` and `AnimationState.time` to do what you are trying. I am not putting this as an answer as I havent tried it. Let me know if this works and I will post the answer

Comment: Thanks Umair, I guess that's more or less what Kardux suggested in his answer.  Cheers.

Comment: @Krystian To be fair Umair was faster than I was but I immediately knew what he proposed was doable since I used it some time ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is something like this :

`yourGameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().GetClip("YOUR_CLIP_NAME").SampleAnimation(yourGameObject, GetComponent<Animation>()["YOUR_CLIP_NAME"].length);`

But this will only work if you know your AnimationClip name ahead...

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Kardux, yep, I know the name of the clip up ahead.